# In MATLAB how can I set all the values of a matrix to string?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a MATLAB matrix, that is 1000x4, to use as an input for a function. I need to add a new column that contains a certain string.  So how can I make a new column where all the values are 'TEST'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's a little unclear what you want, here are some options:

- To make a 1000-by-4 matrix where each row is `'TEST'`, you can use the function [REPMAT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/repmat.html):

  ```
  M = repmat('TEST',1000,1);
  ```
- To add `'TEST'` to the end of each row of a 1000-by-4 matrix of characters, you can use the function [STRCAT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/strcat.html):

  ```
  M = repmat('a',1000,4);  %# Sample matrix filled with 'a'
  M = strcat(M,'TEST');    %# Append 'TEST' to each row of M
  ```
- If your 1000-by-4 matrix is a numeric array instead of an array of characters, you will have to use [cell arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-98.html) to combine the different types of data. Here's one way you can do this:

  ```
  M = rand(1000,4);   %# A matrix of random numeric values
  M = num2cell(M,2);  %# Put each row of M in a cell, making
                      %#   a 1000-by-1 cell array
  M(:,2) = {'TEST'};  %# Add a second column to the cell array,
                      %#   where each cell contains 'TEST'
  ```

Answer (score 0):

A matrix cannot contain a string (like 'TEST').
You need to use a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-98.html#br1xnp2-1)

Answer (score 0):

If this is an existing matrix `M` of cell strings,

```
M(:,end+1) = {'TEST'};
```